# Html3Pdf many image requests

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, jspdf, html2canvas, html2pdf

I'm using htm3pdf library and I'm downloading html string with some divs with images (svg and png/jpg). When I wait for the download, I can see that the network tab is full with repeating image requests and they are slowing down the generation. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uHYCI.png)

My question is: is there a way to prevent all these repeating requests that are slowing down the download?

*im using jpg links and base64 representation for the svg images, even tho the repeating requests are for both cases. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/furtD.png)

I tried every single option for the pdf from the documentation https://socket.dev/npm/package/html3pdf and everything else.

Comment: Hey @KJ I didnt understand if there is a way to cut the steps and remove some of the unnecessary steps so my pages won't make 5 times the same requests

Comment: I didn't understand if you have a solution to my problem.